# Angular nested promises doesn't complete

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

I'm struggling with a consecutive/nested promises in my App. It's for authentication with Firebase but I believe (with what I read, still beginner though) that issue is how I'm nesting the promises and maybe returning them.

I've tried different tutorials that seems to be the same but somehow it doesn't work for me. I can't find what's different from the tutos. I've tried `Promise.all` too but that also didn't work. The nested promise *persistTempUserData* never resolves and therefore doesn't write in the DB. In a desperate attempt I've started playing around with the *return* or just calling the method without returning anything, but that still didn't work. I've also looked at other issues similar to that online but I can't find one that resembles mine.

login Component

```
  public tryGoogleLogin(): void {
    console.log("tryGoogleLogin")
    this.authService.googleLogin().then(() => {
      console.log("Gooogle login worked")
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("Google login didn't workd")
    })
  }
```

Auth Service

```
  public googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    return this.oAuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  private oAuthLogin(provider: auth.GoogleAuthProvider | auth.FacebookAuthProvider): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => { // Also tried not returning a promise and called this... directly. Didn't work
      this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((credential: auth.UserCredential) => {
          if (credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) { // Checked with Console log and is true
            this.persistTempUserData(credential.user).then((res: any) => {
              resolve(); // Never Resolved
            })
          }
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          console.log("signInWithPopup failed", error);
        });
    })
  }

  private persistTempUserData(user: firebase.User): Promise<void>  {
    console.log("persistTempUserData called") // Called
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.angularFirestore.collection(Constants.fbPathRefUsersNode).doc(user.uid)

    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      profilePic: null,
      firstName: this.nameSplitterFirstName(user.displayName),
      lastName: this.nameSplitterLastName(user.displayName),
      email: user.email,
      dOB: null,
      phoneNum: null,
      gender: null,
      institution: null,
      isAccValid: false
    }

    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I corrected 2 problems:

1. persistTempUserData was not returning a promise.
2. No return statement if the below condition evaluated to false.

```
    if (credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) { 
      return this.persistTempUserData(credential.user);
    }
```

```
    
public googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
  return this.oAuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

private oAuthLogin(provider: auth.GoogleAuthProvider | auth.FacebookAuthProvider): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Also tried not returning a promise and called this... directly. Didn't work
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential: auth.UserCredential) => {
        if (credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) { // Checked with Console log and is true
          return this.persistTempUserData(credential.user);
        }
        return reject(new Error("Some Message"));
      }).then((res: any) => {
        return resolve();
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("signInWithPopup failed", error);
        return reject(error);
      });
  })
}

private persistTempUserData(user: firebase.User): Promise<void>  {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("persistTempUserData called") // Called
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.angularFirestore.collection(Constants.fbPathRefUsersNode).doc(user.uid)

    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      profilePic: null,
      firstName: this.nameSplitterFirstName(user.displayName),
      lastName: this.nameSplitterLastName(user.displayName),
      email: user.email,
      dOB: null,
      phoneNum: null,
      gender: null,
      institution: null,
      isAccValid: false
    }
    return resolve(userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    }));
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for time. Unfortunately it still didn't write. Yet you will still have the account created in Anthentication page of Firebase, "persistTempUserData called" written in the log but nothing wrote in the DB. With also no errors at all.